# Parsing string with money to amount and currency code?

Tags: java

So I have these strings:

"$1212,10"
"EUR12,15"
"SEK1500.10"
"50NZD"
"NZ$50,00"

And I need to get the currency code as well as the amount into two separate variables.
Where do I even start?

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions. Like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)([0-9.,]+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("$1212,10");

if(m.find()){
   String cur = m.group(1);
   String amount = m.group(2);
}
```

**Addendum after question changed:**

You can get a list of currency codes through here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

The currency symbols are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol

Jaca supports currencies through Currency.class
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html

You may convert the cur string to the right currency if it exists. You must use the right locale for this to work properly.

Complete (more or less):

```
String YOURSTRING = "SEK1500.10";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)([0-9.,]+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(YOURSTRING);
String cur = null;
String amount = null;

if(m.find()){
    cur = m.group(1);
    amount = m.group(2);
}
else{
    p = Pattern.compile("^([0-9.,]+)(.*)$");
    m = p.matcher(YOURSTRING);

    if(m.find()){
        cur = m.group(2);
        amount = m.group(1);    
    }
    else{
        //no match
    }
}

if (cur!=null){
    Currency foundCurrrency = null;
    for (Currency c : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()){
        if (c.getSymbol(Locale.ENGLISH).equals(cur)){
            //symbol matches!
            foundCurrrency = c;
            break;
        }
        else if (c.getCurrencyCode().equals(cur)){
            //code matches!
            foundCurrrency = c;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (foundCurrrency!=null){
        //YOU FOUND IT
        System.out.println("found currency: "+foundCurrrency);
        System.out.println("amount: "+amount);

    }
}
```

Note: "NZ$50,00" will not work in most cases, since "NZ$" is probably not defined as symbol in the locale you are using. Maybe you need to cycle over all locales and test all symbols against them to find the one you need.

Comment: What if the currency comes after the amount?

Comment: then you can use a second regular expression or make the first one even more advanced. You did not state this in your question though.

Comment: Fair enough. Although the provided code does not offer the currency code, just whatever is in the string.